# Find and replace a screen coords from a list

Tags: python, list, pywinauto, coords

I'm using OpenCV to find some images on screen and return it into a list of coords so pywinauto click on them, so everytime an image is found it gives a list like this:

`[(297, 323), (390, 323), (297, 370), (437, 393), (314, 349), (408, 349)]`

I want to get rid of `(297, 323)` and `(390, 323)` for example, how is it possible?

I have been searching for hours but my english ain't perfect so I'm always finding the wrong answers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove all occurences:

```python
a = [(297, 323), (390, 323), (297, 370), (437, 393), (314, 349), (408, 349)]
b = [x for x in a if x != (297, 323) and x!= (390, 323)]
print(b)
```

if you just want to remove the first occurence:

```python
a = [(297, 323), (390, 323), (297, 370), (437, 393), (314, 349), (408, 349)]
a.remove((297, 323))
a.remove((390, 323))
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

So if I understand well, ```x!=``` is here to delete the coords?

EDIT: Also ```a.remove()``` give me this error: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'```

Comment: Not exactly - that whole line is using list comprehension, which you can read about more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). What is does is that it loops through the old list and only adds elements that satisfy the condition, so elements that are not equal to (297, 323) and also (390, 323)

Comment: The error means you are calling the remove method on a string. This method only works for lists @Clementinise

Comment: I already tried with .replace() on my list and got this same error, that's why this post exist. I got really confused on why it was saying it was a string since it is a list x)

But the use of ```b = [x for x in a if x != (297, 323) and x!= (390, 323)]``` work so I think I will be good with that until I found the issue :D